# Why does my Flask webhook never receive, acknowledge and process alerts coming from TradingView?

Tags: flask, alert

My Google Cloud Functions (GCF) hosted Flask app has a webhook script that is unable to process the Alerts received from TradingView (does not even acknowledge whether it received the webhook alerts at all regardless of correct JSON format and correct webhook URL in place). TradingView has the following JSON:

```json
{
  "ticker": "SOL-USD",
  "quantity": "0.005",
  "action": "buy",
  "security_passphrase": "PASSTHISALERT"
}
```

And, my GCF hosted Flask app has the following webhook script:

```py
# Receive TradingView signals/alerts
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        ticker = data.get('ticker')
        quantity = data.get('quantity')
        action = data.get('action')
        passphrase = data.get('security_passphrase')

        # Verify the security passphrase
        if passphrase != PASS_PHRASE:
            raise ValueError("Invalid security passphrase")

        if not ticker or not quantity or not action:
            raise ValueError("Invalid TradingView alert data")
            
        # Determine side based on action ("buy" or "sell")
        side = 'BUY' if action.lower() == 'buy' else 'SELL'
            
        # Coinbase Advanced Trade API Configuration
        response = cb_create_market_order(ticker, quantity, side)
            
        return flask.jsonify({'success': True}), 200
    
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error processing trading data: %s", e, exc_info=True)
        return flask.jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500
    
    # Check the status code inside the try-except block
    if response.status_code != 200:
        response_data = response.text  # Get the response text
        raise Exception(f"Error placing order: {response_data}")
```

When a method is defined as shown above `def webhook()`, the server responses with "500 Internal Server Error" showing

> TypeError: webhook() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

If replaced with `def webhook(request)`, then that error is gone, but the webhook never processes alerts received from TradingView. There must be something stupid simple that I'm missing here. Sincerely like to thank you for helping me address this.

After building the app in Google Cloud Functions, and ran several tests with JSON and CURL snippets which all passes gracefully. The server is up and running flawlessly. But for some strange reason, webhook alert doesn't trigger the app to respond at all.

Comment: `def webhook(request)` looks questionable - you may shadow global `request` with the name of your parameter.

Comment: You meant: def webhook(request_data):
    # Function implementation here

Comment: Yes, at least it will make use of `request` (`flask.request`) below. Btw, do you have some decorators or before request processing, those insert additional parameters into route handlers?

Comment: Yes, this one: @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])